# What is does a resolution of "11.8 bits" mean when looking at a digital signal?

Tags: digital-logic, sensor, datasheet

I recently picked up a project at work involving a magnetic sensor. When reading the data sheet, it lists a range of resolutions from 11-bit to 12.8 bits,  11.8 bits being nominal. I can understand these maybe being an average, but they are listed as output resolutions. Is this common and something I have simply never seen before, and if so, what is meant by "11.8" bits?

Thank you.

Comment: Citation please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ENOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_number_of_bits) (Effective number of bits) is defined as:

\$ \text {ENOB} = \frac{SINAD - 10 \log_{10}(3/2)}{20 \log_{10}(2)} \$

SINAD is the signal to noise and distortion ratio (in dB)

So, it's the resolution of an equivalent ideal ADC. Resolution in bits is \$\log_2(n)\$ where *n* is the total number of output codes, so an 11.8 bit ADC would have 3566 distinct output codes.

Comment: This makes sense in the context of the data sheet. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: It could also be dynamic range

Comment: @HKOB ENOB is a way to describe dynamic range.

Comment: ENOB and DR are different measures. One incorporates linearity the other one doesn't.

Comment: @HKOB That's one definition, for sure, popular with chip suppliers. But others (eg. Rohde & Schwarz) use SINAD as their definition of dynamic range. It's rather a [loose](http://www.electronicdesign.com/community-home/understanding-your-signal-analyzer-s-dynamic-range) term.